# how to use another activity element in navigation drawer class?

Tags: android, android-studio, button, android-activity, click

I am using navigation drawer activity. So activity don't have class. only have layouts. navigation drawer only have class. so I want to write a code in that class. i am using a button but application not working when start navigation activity. please help me.

```js
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    
    FragmentManager mfragementManger;
    Button BTNeditprofile;
    EditText ETprofilename;
    




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        
        BTNeditprofile = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BTNeditprofile);
        ETprofilename = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETprofilename);

        BTNeditprofile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                
            }
        });
```

This is other activity elements.
when i write a code to click, get error after run

```js
BTNeditprofile = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BTNeditprofile);
        ETprofilename = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETprofilename);

        BTNeditprofile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you post your layouts? If your app is crashing also add your crash logs.

Comment: android studio did not show any error. application get error unfortunately error. if i make button function.

Comment: Yes by "app" I meant your application, not Android Studio. Post your logcat output if your android app is crashing.